# Wix 3.11 Bundles & Upgrades

Tags: wix, bundle, upgrade, arp

I searched high and low for this and to all intents and purposes what I'm doing should work but doesn't seem to.
I have the following Bundle definition

```
<Bundle Name="My Bundle"
            Version="1.0.0.0"
            Manufacturer="My Manufacturer"
            Copyright="My Manufacturer Ltd"
            UpgradeCode="0F9FFB5C-4FC4-4AC0-AA45-C0713826DADE"
```

It's simple, it just chains an ExePackage for the VC++ runtime and an MsiPackage for my own myApp installer.

I install, ARP shows My Bundle v1.0.0.0, the VC++ runtime and of course myApp v1.0.0.0

On updating my app and the associated MsiPackage to be 1.0.1.0 and the bundle version to be 1.0.1.0, ARP now shows My Bundle v1.0.0.0, My Bundle v1.0.1.0, the VC++ runtime and of course myApp v1.0.1.0

Why is the bundle showing twice, why isn't 1.0.0.0 version removed?

I can get around this by setting DisableRemove & DisableModify bundle attributes but this seems like a workaround rather than a solution

Not looking to update to WiX v4 just now.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: It sounds like the uninstall of the older version is failing for some reason. I'd start by looking at the log file for the uninstall of the old bundle during the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Checked the logs and it did have 0x80070643 "Process returned error: 0x643" & "Failed to execute EXE package" errors (even though it went onto install... Went back to the bundle wxs and removed all the fluff, specifically the ProductSearch for VC++. Voila it now works as it should, not sure why but at least it works. Something to look into at a later date for me, more pressing matters to attend to just now.